# client server using TCP in C

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

I am working on client server project where I have to search data requested by client from a file that is on the server side.

My code on client side:

```
        printf("Enter data to search: \n");
        fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        send(s,buf, strlen(buf),0);
        printf("Result of your search: ");
        if(len = recv(s, buf, sizeof(buf),0)>0)
        printf("\nMessage Received From Server -\n  %s\n",buf);
```

my code on server side:

```
            fp=fopen("courses.txt","r");

            len=recv(new_s,buf,sizeof(buf),0);

            char temp[256],tmp[512];
            char *search;



            while(fgets(tmp, 512, fp)!=NULL)
            {
                search= strstr(tmp, buf);
                if(search)
                {    
                    send(new_s,tmp,strlen(tmp),0);

                }  

            }
```

The strstr() always returns a null value therefore it never enters the if statement.

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: "does not seem to work" is not an adequate problem statement. And please proved a [mcve].

Comment: @a_s741  fgets appends the new line character '\n' I think you should remove it like buf[ strcspn( buf, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

Comment: strstr() does not search from my file and does not return anything. when I tried printing it sometimes returned me the whole file.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If he removes it, how will the server know when it has received the entire query?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz He can remove it for example at the server side.

Comment: You have two problems. One is that you ignore the return value of `recv`, so you have no idea how many bytes you received. But the other is more basic -- you do not have any protocol that specifies how messages are to be exchanged. This seems to be a requirement for your use case. The query is a message, so you need a message protocol, which TCP is not.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But before you can use `strcspn`, he'd have to already have converted it into a C-style string. That seems a bit illogical and backwards to me. (Since he needs to find the newline to convert it to a string anyway.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Then the code will be even simpler. Just check the last character.

Answer (score 2):

TCP is not a message protocol. If you want to send and receive messages (which your query is) you need a message protocol. Start by defining precisely how messages are bounded (at the byte level) and then write code to send and receive a message.

Also, don't ignore the return value of `recv`. How do you know how many bytes you received? And don't use functions like `strlen` and `strcpy` for anything but a C-style string. For convenience, you can make your send and receive message functions take and return C-style strings. But don't assume data on the wire will be a C-style string until your code makes it one.

Comment: There should be a canonical for this - there are thousands of these 'ignore streaming nature of TCP', 'misuse of str* calls' and 'failure to completely and correctly handle the result returned from recv).

Comment: Yeah. This is one of those things were everybody's first attempt makes every possible mistake. Unfortunately, even if you don't fix everything it still might happen to work sometimes by luck/accident. We probably do have a canonical answer somewhere.